# Django - Defaulting a Form Field's Value

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

When I am about to create a model instance via the UI, I'd like to default a field (let's say 'status' to value 'draft'). I tried to do this in the Form in `**init**():
** Model**

```
class ForecastConfiguration(Control):
  uuid = kp.ObjectIDField()
  name = kp.ObjectNameField()
  description = kp.ObjectDescriptionField()
  status = models.ForeignKey(Status, blank=False, null=False, editable=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

**Form**

```
class ForecastConfigurationCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

  class Meta:
      model = ForecastConfiguration
      exclude = ['uuid', 'hierarchy_nodes']

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

      # default status
      self.fields['status'] = ModelChoiceField(queryset=ObjectStatus.get_object_status_list(self, is_form=True))

      # status is defaulted when created; will get updated by planning element status
      self.fields['status'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True
```

This works fine: the value is defaulted. However, when I submit the form I get a validation error saying that this field cannot be empty and in the form, the value is empty.

I tried doing this in the view as well (same result):

**View**

```
class ForecastConfigurationCreateView(CreateView):
  model = ForecastConfiguration
  form_class = ForecastConfigurationCreateForm
  template_name = 'frontend/base/planning_create.html'
  object = None
  # success_url = ''

   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    # default status to 'Draft'
    status_id = Status.objects.get(name=constant.status['draft']).uuid
    form = ForecastConfigurationCreateForm(initial={'status': status_id})

    member_formset = MemberFormSet()


    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'member_formset': member_formset})
```

**Edit**

This is how the `status` field is defaulted when loading:
[image: on load]

After saving, the value is still there but the form complains:
[image]

Using `readonly` as the attribute makes the field read-only but it still can be edited:
[image]

Comment: what about the rendered page? Do you see form field filled by default?

Comment: @VaibhavVishal - I just edited my question. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your initial values when you instantiate your form in the view. Something like so,

```
form = ArticleForm(initial={'headline': 'Initial headline'}, instance=article)
```

Check the django docs for model forms right [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you provide where exactly I need to put this?

Comment: In your view. I see in your question that you have already included that. But i dont understand why you set your initial value to a django object. Did you try to set it to the actuall pk value of that Status object?

Comment: So, in the get method, I removed everything except for `form = ForecastConfigurationCreateForm(initial={'status': status_id})` (and of course setting the `status_id`) however, on save the form will again drop the status value just I explained it in the screenshot.

Comment: Did you try setting the value to the pk of the obect like so, `form = ForecastConfigurationCreateForm(initial={'status': status_id.id})` since your status_id is an object and an actual value like an int for example

Comment: Tried that as well, same behavior.

Comment: Could you add your model and form code to the question so I can try to simulate your issue at my end.

Comment: Its your disabled field that is giving you the issue :s. The status field does not get sent in the request when the field is disabled for some reason. It worked just fine for me when removed. You need to set the field to readonly instead of disabled. A simple search will tell you how to set readonly in the forms HTML.

Comment: The problem with `readonly` is that the field is greyed out, but can still be edited in Django. I tried this before and decided to go with `disabled` - I added a screenshot into the original question. But you are right, with this the form is validated ok.

Comment: I get you, your other option is to keep the select as disabled, and add a hidden field for the status with the value you need. This way your select is not clickable and your hidden value is sent.

Comment: Yes, but that sounds way to weird, no? To me this seems to be a bug in Django, would you agree?

Comment: Not really. Its more of an html issue where anything with a disabled tag is basically ignored regardless of how you post your form or which framework you use i guess.

Comment: hmm, and when it is set to 'read-only' that you can still change it?

Comment: That again is an html attribute, nothing to do with django really.

Comment: An upvote on any helpful comments would be much so appreciated :)